# ASP.NET MVC System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`Model’ to type ‘Model’

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have this line of code in my controller:

```
BlogClass blogClass = (BlogClass)dbBlog.Data.Where(model => model.category == id.ToString());

return View(blogClass);
```

I get this error:

```
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`Model’ to type ‘Model’.
```

I know I can get rid of it by getting first or default, however I want all the results.

Because in my view I have this:

```
@model Project.Models.BlogClass
```

My question is how do I get all the results in a class?

Additional Info:

```
private Blog dbBlog = new Blog();

public class BlogClass
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Title")]
        public string title { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Post")]
        public string post { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Date")]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public string date { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Featured Image")]
        public string featuredImage { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Category")]
        public string category { get; set; }
    }

    public class Blog : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<BlogClass> Data { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: What is the type of `dbBlog.Data` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Where` method returns a collection. You are trying to cast a collection (*specifically `IQueryable`*)to a single `BlogClass` object! That does not makes sense!

If you are looking for only a single item matching your where clause, use `FirstOrDefault` method.

> I know I can get rid of it by getting first or default, however I want
>   all the results.

If you need all of them, you should not cast it to a single instance. Also change your view so that it is strongly typed to a collection.

```
var blogList = dbBlog.Data.Where(model => model.category == id.ToString()).ToList();    
return View(blogList);
```

Now the view should be strongly typed to a list of BlogClass

```
@model List<ReplaceYourNameSpaceHere.BlogClass>
@foreach(var b in Model)
{
  <h2>@b.title</b>
}
```

I also suggest to use [PascalCasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PascalCase) for C# classes. Also what is the point of having the `Class` suffix for the class name ? You know it is a class :)

```
public class Blog
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thhhhank you very much.